# Consumir un servicio en Visual Basic publicado en PHP

Tags: php, mysql, vb.net

Como puedo extraer los datos consumiendo un  webservice desde **`PHP`** y me retorne en un `datagridview` de **`Visual Basic`** como prodran observar en una consulta varios datos

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports DESCARGAPEDIDO.WsSurtioficce


Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        If My.Application.CommandLineArgs.Count > 0 Then
            Operador = My.Application.CommandLineArgs(0).ToString()
            NombreBD = My.Application.CommandLineArgs(4).ToString()
            ServidorBD = My.Application.CommandLineArgs(5).ToString()
            For N_PARAMETRO = 0 To My.Application.CommandLineArgs.Count - 1
                If N_PARAMETRO >= CAMPOFINAL Then
                    G_CONEXIONBIROBIDSA += My.Application.CommandLineArgs(N_PARAMETRO).ToString.Trim + " "
                End If
            Next
        End If
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(Operador) Then
            Operador = "ADM"
        End If
        ObtieneConexion()
        'configuraGrid()
        'configuraGrid2()
        BuscaCabecera()
    End Sub
    Private Sub ObtieneConexion()
        cn = con.ConexionSQL(NombreBD, ServidorBD, UserBD, PasswordBD)
        G_CONEXIONBIROBIDSA = cn.ConnectionString
        cn.Dispose()
        cn.Close()
    End Sub
    Private Sub BuscaCabecera()
        Dim Array As Char
        Array = ObjWsSurt.orden_pedido(fecha.Text)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = Array
    End Sub
```

Comment: la base y la consulta esta en un hosting ya agrege las referencias web de la pagina en visual basic pero al momento de llamar a la consulta no retorna

Comment: busco al webservices desde el visual basic

Comment: Bien Leonardo.. ahora va quedando mejor salvo por el tema de las imagenes. Ahora podrias explicar cual es el problema que estas teniendo? el web service anda? No recibes la respuesta en VB?

Comment: tu pregunta es como consumir un servicio en vb.net publicado en PHP?

Comment: claro no recibo la respuesta lo probe utilizando soapui y tengop respuesta pero en el vb no me retorna es en la funcion privada llamada buscar cabecera envio el parametro de busqueda que es la fecha para que me retorne la consulta en el datagridview pero no es la correcta

Comment: claro al realizar la consulta no me retorna los datos en el datagridview JackNavaRow

Comment: por favor coloca el codigo de como estas consumiendo el WS de PHP y que error te esta devolviendo

Comment: JackNavaRow  halli se encuentra el codigo fuente del visual basic

Comment: que te retorna el WebService al consumir en VB.net da un error?

Comment: El webservice retorna un char? y eso se lo estas pasando como datasource a la grilla? ahi esta el problema...

Comment: me muestra un mensaje Excepción no controlada del tipo 'System.InvalidOperationException' en System.Xml.dll

Información adicional: Error en el documento XML (1, 479en el VB en un cuadro de dialogo